# Xamarin Forms trouble with SQLite and await

Tags: c#, sqlite, async-await, xamarin.forms

I'm using the sqlite-net-pcl nuget, in my view model I am trying to get the list of announcements from my database

```
    private SQLiteAsyncConnection connection;
    public ObservableCollection<Announcement> AnnouncementList { get; private set; }

    public AnnouncementsViewModel() {
        connection = DependencyService.Get<ISQLiteDb>().GetConnection();
        Initialize();
    }    

    public async void Initialize() {
        await connection.CreateTableAsync<Announcement>();
        var announcements = await connection.Table<Announcement>().ToListAsync();
        AnnouncementList = new ObservableCollection<Announcement>(announcements);
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("***********************************");
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(AnnouncementList.Count);
    }
```

in my code behind, in the constructor:

```
 BindingContext = new AnnouncementsViewModel();
 InitializeComponent();
 var list = (BindingContext as AnnouncementsViewModel).AnnouncementList;
```

The error I get is:

> System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance
>   of an object.

I put a break point in my viewModel, when it arrives to the first await it returns to the code behind and the App crashes. I get the null exception because the AnnouncementList is not filled in the viewModel and it didn't print the stars.
How can I solve this problem?

Thanks

Comment: What's the callstack of the exception?

Comment: `(BindingContext as AnnouncementsViewModel)` i bet this is `null`

Comment: @j0ey_wh I put a breakpoint on this line it gives me Could not resolve type: AnnouncementsViewModel

Comment: @RichardSzalay how do i get the callstack?

Comment: do it like this:
`var vieModel = BindingContext as AnnouncementsViewModel`; is the `vieModel` null?

Comment: No, it didn't stop  or crash on this line the null exception is again on the var list

Answer (score 0):

You can't just call your async `Initialize()` method in a sync way like that. It will return immediately and by the time you get around to using `AnnouncementList`, `Initialize` isn't finished running yet and it is still null.

It's not an ideal solution but you should add `.Wait()` after `Initialize()` to ensure it completes before you exit the constructor.

I say 'not ideal' because depending on your context `Wait()` might block.  If that happens you're probably better off doing that initialization work before constructing your ViewModel, using only 'proper' awaiting, and passing `AnnouncementsList` into the constructor.

Comment: I could not out .Wait() because Initialize() returns void I have changed the ViewModel

Comment: To solve that particular issue just change the return type to Task.

Comment: When I run I only get a black screen

Answer (score 0):

The new ViewModel:

```
  public AnnouncementsViewModel() {
        connection = DependencyService.Get<ISQLiteDb>().GetConnection();
    }
  public async void GetAnnouncement() {
        await connection.CreateTableAsync<Announcement>();
        var announcements = await connection.Table<Announcement>().ToListAsync();
        AnnouncementList = new ObservableCollection<Announcement>(announcements);            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("***********************************");
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(AnnouncementList.Count);
    }
```

Then In my code behind:

```
  protected override async void OnAppearing() {
        (BindingContext as AnnouncementsViewModel).GetAnnouncement();
        if ((BindingContext as AnnouncementsViewModel).list != null)
            classAnnouncementListView.ItemsSource = (BindingContext as AnnouncementsViewModel).list;
        base.OnAppearing();
    }
```

Comment: Edit the question to add that, rather than add an answer.